# Where in CentOS does program start at boot if it's not in init.d?

Tags: centos, upstart, init, gitlab

I have installed a software (GitLab) on CentOS. It works well, but this GitLab starts at boot and I don't want that. 
So I took a look at `/etc/init.d` in order to disable it with `chkconfig`, but my problem is that there is no `gitlab` script in it, so I can't disable it.

So here is my question: is there any other place in CentOS where I can find programs executed at CentOS start up? Or more directly, if someone knows how to disable GitLab from start up without using `init.d`, I am interested!

Comment: GitLab seems to be start by `initctl`. If I type the command `initctl list`, I can see this job: `gitlab-runsvdir start/running, process 1008`. 
The corresponding start script is `/etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.conf`. But I didn't find how to disable it :/

Comment: What CentOS version do you have?

Comment: I am using CentOS 6.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) file `/etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.conf` and comment out the line `start on runlevel [2345]`

Resulting file `/etc/init/gitlab-runsvdir.conf`:

```
#start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown
respawn
post-stop script
   # To avoid stomping on runsv's owned by a different runsvdir
   # process, kill any runsv process that has been orphaned, and is
   # now owned by init (process 1).
   pkill -HUP -P 1 runsv$
end script
exec /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start
```

The line `start on level [2345]` is basically saying the script `/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start` will be executed on [runlevel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel)s 2, 3, 4, and 5

After you have commented it out you can still manage the service using the following commands:

`start gitlab-runsvdir  # start the gitlab service`

`stop gitlab-runsvdir   # stop the gitlab service`

`status gitlab-runsvdir # get status of gitlab service`